# Crash When accessing RLMResults count

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am getting a weird crash when I access my RLMResults count,
this crash occurs sometimes and sometimes don't mostly I have seen when there is 0 result in RLMResult it crashes.

I have also seen the similar issue on GitHub but somehow it is closed without resolving
https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4960

**MY CODE**

```
-(BOOL)checkIfSyncRequired{
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.appLocalEditTimeStamp > self.lastSyncServerTimestamp"];
    RLMResults *results = [HKCrashObject objectsWithPredicate:predicate];

    if (results.count) {//crash occurs on calls.count 
        //do something with results but it crashes before only
        return true;
    }else{

        return false;
    }
}
```

**HKCrashObject CLASS**

```
@interface HKCrashObject : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * customId;
@property (nonatomic, assign) long lastSyncServerTimestamp;
@property (nonatomic, assign) long appLocalEditTimeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * otherProperties;
@end
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
(lldb) bt
Realm was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
    * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
        frame #0: 0x000000010ec69f9c Realm`bool realm::Array::compare_leafs_4<realm::Greater, (realm::Action)0, 32ul, bool (*)(long long), 32ul>(realm::Array const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::QueryState<long long>*, bool (*)(long long)) const + 172
        frame #1: 0x000000010ec688c8 Realm`bool realm::Array::compare_leafs<realm::Greater, (realm::Action)0, 32ul, bool (*)(long long)>(realm::Array const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::QueryState<long long>*, bool (*)(long long)) const + 504
        frame #2: 0x000000010ec68210 Realm`bool realm::Array::compare_leafs<realm::Greater, (realm::Action)0, bool (*)(long long)>(realm::Array const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::QueryState<long long>*, bool (*)(long long)) const + 736
        frame #3: 0x000000010ec67b90 Realm`realm::TwoColumnsNode<realm::Column<long long>, realm::Greater>::find_first_local(unsigned long, unsigned long) + 384
        frame #4: 0x000000010ecbff93 Realm`realm::ParentNode::aggregate_local(realm::QueryStateBase*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::SequentialGetterBase*) + 83
        frame #5: 0x000000010ec48a2a Realm`realm::Query::aggregate_internal(realm::Action, realm::DataType, bool, realm::ParentNode*, realm::QueryStateBase*, unsigned long, unsigned long, realm::SequentialGetterBase*) const + 314
        frame #6: 0x000000010ec4eb00 Realm`realm::Query::count(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long) const + 480
        frame #7: 0x000000010e9c5b2f Realm`realm::Results::size(this=<unavailable>) at results.cpp:136 [opt]
      * frame #8: 0x000000010ea5b3b0 Realm`::-[RLMResults count]() [inlined] -[RLMResults count]::$_1::operator()() const at RLMResults.mm:137 [opt]
        frame #9: 0x000000010ea5b3a2 Realm`::-[RLMResults count]() [inlined] auto translateRLMResultsErrors<-[RLMResults count]::$_1>(aggregateMethod=<unavailable>) at RLMResults_Private.hpp:57 [opt]
        frame #10: 0x000000010ea5b3a2 Realm`::-[RLMResults count](self=<unavailable>, _cmd=<unavailable>) at RLMResults.mm:137 [opt]
        frame #11: 0x000000010c31842f Jobi`-[myCallsViewController checkIfSyncRequired](self=0x00007fd2b174b990, _cmd="checkIfSyncRequired") at myCallsViewController.m:415
        frame #12: 0x000000010c313939 Jobi`-[myCallsViewController viewWillAppear:](self=0x00007fd2b174b990, _cmd="viewWillAppear:", animated=YES) at myCallsViewController.m:85
        frame #13: 0x000000010f61cdc0 UIKit`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 442
        frame #14: 0x000000010f61d62f UIKit`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 131
        frame #15: 0x000000010f67b9c0 UIKit`-[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 291
        frame #16: 0x000000010f61cdc0 UIKit`-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 442
        frame #17: 0x000000010f61d62f UIKit`-[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 131
        frame #18: 0x000000010f648d5c UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1183
        frame #19: 0x000000010f65f5e2 UIKit`-[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 714
        frame #20: 0x000000010f6608cc UIKit`-[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
        frame #21: 0x000000010f8b8bd7 UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
        frame #22: 0x000000012c9d761c UIKit`-[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 42
        frame #23: 0x000000010f542808 UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
        frame #24: 0x000000010e7ec61a QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
        frame #25: 0x000000010e7f082b QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 395
        frame #26: 0x000000010e77729f QuartzCore`CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 343
        frame #27: 0x000000010e7a4940 QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::commit() + 568
        frame #28: 0x000000010e7a56be QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
        frame #29: 0x00000001126fa607 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
        frame #30: 0x00000001126fa55e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
        frame #31: 0x00000001126deb81 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1537
        frame #32: 0x00000001126de30b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
        frame #33: 0x00000001154fda73 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
        frame #34: 0x000000010f4730b7 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
        frame #35: 0x000000010c2df85f Jobi`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007ffee3a450d8) at main.m:14
        frame #36: 0x000000011399f955 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
        frame #37: 0x000000011399f955 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @InfinityJames & Er. Khatri did you ever resolve the issue? Facing the same problem